# How to check character presence in a variable via database call in php

Tags: php

Here am trying to check the presence of certain character in a string with database call in php

With the code below it works excellent..

```
$find= ['a','b','c'];
$mystring = "am here for you";

if(array_intersect($find, str_split($mystring))) {
    echo "character found";
}else{

echo "character not found";

}
```

**Here is my Issue:** I want to implement it the database way.

To this effect, I want to have the **$find** variables data to come from my database so that I can now perform check.

So in my database, I inserted it as follows

`insert into checkd(find_character)values("['a','b','c']");`

and it was successfully inserted..

This is how I now retrieve it

```
$result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM checkd');
$result->execute(array());
while ($row = $result->fetch()) 
{
$ckk= $row['find_character'];

 //The result was printed successfully.
//echo "$ckk";
}
```

When I echoed the result from database, it was successful as can see `['a','b','c']`

Now I want perform check based on database result but its not showing whether the character I find is present or not using
the code below.

```
$find_db= $ckk;
$mystring_db = "am here for you bb";

if(array_intersect($find_db, str_split($mystring_db))) {
    echo "character found";
}else{

echo "character not found";

}
```

Any idea on why its not working with **database** results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because in the database you are saving the array as a string, and the `array_intersect` function requires an array.

What you must do is convert the string to an array.

You could do the following:

- Save in the database: `a, b, c`
- Use explode to convert the string to an array:

  `$find_db = explode(",", $ckk);`

Comment: Thank you so much. you really save me alot of headaches